# Help with combinatorial problem

Tags: combinatorics

A rectangle is divided by vertical and horizontal lines into unit squares, arranged in m rows and n columns. How many rectangles are in the resulting drawing? The initial rectangle is also counted. Rectangles of all sizes are also counted. Each rectangle must have a positive length and positive width, that is, lines and points are not counted as rectangles.

Comment: Hint: how many ways can you choose the left and right borders?

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I can choose the borders m(m+1)/2 and n(n+1)/2 ways. Right? So the answer must be mn(m+1)(n+1)/4?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Number of rectangles in a grid of size at least $W \times H$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2674022/number-of-rectangles-in-a-grid-of-size-at-least-w-times-h)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get amount of submatrixes from $a \times b $matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1368912/get-amount-of-submatrixes-from-a-times-b-matrix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any rectangle is determined by its boundary, and so it is enough to calculate the number of ways of choosing two distinct vertical lines and two distinct horizontal lines from the given collection of vertical and horizontal lines. Since there are $m$ rows and $n$ columns, we have $m+1$ horizontal lines and $n+1$ horizontal columns. Therefore, the total number of rectangles in this arrangement are
$${{m+1}\choose{2}}{{n+1}\choose{2}} = \frac{mn(m+1)(n+1)}{4}$$